# What are the options to use JDBC in a non-blocking way in Play?

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework

I wonder what is the best (recommended, approved etc.) way to do non-blocking JDBC queries in Play! application using Play's connection pool (in Scala and to PostgreSQL if it matters)? I understand that JDBC is definitely blocking per se, but surely there are approaches to do the calls in separated threads (e.g. using futures or actors) to avoid blocking of the calling thread.

Suppose I decided to wrap the calls in futures, which execution context should I use, the Play's default one? Or it's better to create separated execution context for handling DB queries?

I know that there are some libraries for this like [postgresql-async](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async), but I really want to understand the mechanics :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Suppose I decided to wrap the calls in futures, which execution context should I use, the Play's default one? Or it's better to create separated execution context for handling DB queries?

It is better to use separate execution context in this case. This way there will be no chance that your non-blocking jobs (most of the default Play's stuff) submitted to default execution context will be jammed by blocking JDBC calls in jobs you submit to the same execution context.

I suggest to read [this](http://sadache.tumblr.com/post/42351000773/async-reactive-nonblocking-threads-futures-executioncont) (especially second part) to get a general idea of how you could deal with execution contexts in different situations (including case with blocking database queries), and then refer [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools) to get more details on configuring your scenario in Play.

Comment: Just a comment from the front lines on this. We're using Play 2.3.x in Java 8 (not Scala) and also Postgres. I wrestled with this exact question, and ultimately concluded that, at least in Java, there was too much boilerplate overhead to put JDBC calls in a different execution context. So we're (unfortunately) going with the old thread-per-request paradigm. No one was able to give me an example of Java + JDBC in a different execution context, though I'm still open minded to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I decided to wrap the calls in futures, which execution
>   context should I use, the Play's default one?

If you do that, you gain nothing, it's like not using futures at all. Wrapping blocking calls in futures only helps you if you execute them in separate execution contexts.

In Play, you can basically choose between the following two approaches when dealing with blocking IO:

- Turn Play into a one-thread-per-request Framework by drastically increasing the default execution context. No futures needed, just call your blocking database as always. Simple, but not the intention behind Play
- Create specific execution contexts for your blocking IO-calls and gain fine-grained control of what you are doing

See the [docs: "Understanding Play thread pools"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools)

Comment: It might need clarification why I'm talking about the default context. As I've understood from Play's [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools) there are several thread pool. Requests are being handled in a pool called "Play Internal Thread Pool" which must never ever be blocked. But there is also a pool called "Play default thread pool", which size can be increased and which could be used (as I understand) for blocking operations also.

Comment: You're right, there's also an internal thread pool which should  never ever block, but this is not the place for your application logic and doesn't need to be considered. You can do blocking things in the default threadpool, but then you need a certain amount of threads; otherwise, your application will "hang" for a short period of time. Imagine you have a 4 core CPU and a default execution context with 4 threads, an ideal setup for asynchronous, non-blocking IO. But if you use blocking IO with this setup, 4 simultaneous requests are enough to make new requests wait.